# Field value from name in thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I would like to convert this code to template that I can include by passing a name of field like that:

```
<div th:object="${form}">
  <div th:replace="'templates/fields' :: input_text (fieldName='user.userName')" />
</div>

<th:block th:fragment="input_text"> 
    <input class="form-control"
           type="text"
           th:field="*{fieldName}"/>
</th:block>
```

The code above does not work unless I change from
 `th:field="*{fieldName}"` to `th:field="*{__${fieldName}__}"`

Is there any way to do that without usage of preprocessing?

I actually need something like Fields.getValue(String fieldName);

@Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String test(@ModelAttribute("form") TestForm form) {
    return "test"
  }

@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String test(@Valid @ModelAttribute("form") TestForm form, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    return "test_success"
  }
```

bean

```
public class TestForm implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 123L;

  private String something;

  private String somethingElse;

  // ...
}
```

Comment: could you provide the java code for your form object and the controller code?

Comment: Actually I am looking for a generic solution not for a solution to a particular case. @Controller and bean implementations should not be important here. Anyway I have added them to my question.